# List of products with certain status at any timepoint

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift containing id, status and the timestamp the status was set. The ids are not unique, for example a book was available at one point, then it was sold, then we received it as a return from the customer and the status is on cleaning, and after cleaning it will receive again the status available.

| book_id | status | status_valid_from |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | available | 2022-08-02 13:04:43.000 |
| 103 | cleaning | 2022-08-03 10:20:21.000 |
| 104 | cleaning | 2022-08-04 13:55:04.000 |
| 101 | sold | 2022-08-05 19:29:41.000 |
| 104 | available | 2022-08-06 06:14:33.000 |
| 105 | cleaning | 2022-08-07 15:43:12.000 |
| 108 | available | 2022-08-08 11:03:24.000 |
| 101 | cleaning | 2022-08-11 07:28:21.000 |
| 124 | sold | 2022-08-11 09:41:53.000 |
| 101 | available | 2022-08-11 16:49:34.000 |

Every time the book gets a new status, a new row is created in the table to record it.

**The question:** How do I select the list of ids having status "available" at a specific time point?

For example:

- at 2022-08-03 10:20:21.000 the query should return as available only id 101.
- at 2022-08-11 07:40:27.000 the query should return as available the ids 104, 108.
- at 2022-08-11 16:51:25.000 the query should return as available the ids 104, 108, 101.

What I tried:

```
select *
from table
where status = 'available'
and status_valid_from >= specific_timestamp
```

However, it works for books that had the status set to available only once, and only if the status wasn't changed afterwards. What I'd like to find out is how to select the correct list using a code that's valid for all cases.

Comment: add AND operator, AND status = 'available'

Comment: @learning you are right, I did that but I forgot to copy it here. Unfortunately it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on window functions; they are very helpful in situations like this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

As I understand your question you want to find, for each id, the last status for that id and then find all the id that have status "available".  Correct?

Window functions allow you to partition the data by id, and find the last status by date.  Doing this for a dataset that only has data up to the date of interest will give you the latest status for each id as of that point in time.  Them just select those that are available.

```
select book_id, status
from (
  select book_id, status,
    row_number() over (partition by book_id order by status_valid_from desc) as row_num
  from <table>
  where status_valid_from <= <date-of-interest>
)
where row_num = 1
```